# Generate uuid in windows postgresql

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I have a postgresql 9 installation on windows, which doesn't have built in uuid generator. There is OSSD package, which can be bound to postgresql as uuid generator, but it's for *nix only (I think).

How can I generate uuid in windows postgresql?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The one-click installer from EnterpriseDB does have it. The DLL is called "uuid-ossp.dll" and resides in "(Postgres' installation directory)\lib" and the installation SQL script is called "uuid-ossp.sql" and resides in "(Postgres' installation directory)\share\contrib". You have to execute the last one in the DB of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! To add to the answer, I have to login to the db that needs to generate uuid (not postgres db) as administrator / postgres user (not normal user).

Comment: Yes, the ["Additional Supplied Modules"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html) section of the manual mentions that.

Comment: on postgresql 9.1, you simply execute CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp"

Answer (score 3):

The [uuid-ossp-module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/uuid-ossp.html) in the contrib, does work on Windows XP 32 bits. The 64 bits version is not available yet, the OSSP UUID library project has to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, I did the following to generate UUIDs:

Log into the server using this command on Command Prompt:

```
psql -U postgres
```

This is basically accessing PostgreSQL as root.

Then select the database you want this function to be available in:

```
postgres=# \c <name of database>
```

Then execute the following:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Then test by immediately executing:

```
SELECT uuid_generate_v4();
```

I recommend you review the [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/uuid-ossp.html) documentation on the available UUID functions.