# Save an image into database with a random name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, postgresql

Good morning people, i've been trying to solve this for some days, but i must admit im kind of new on this of programming.

Actually im making a news website, and for the news management im having a small problem, i want that, when i click to save the pic it get's a random name, not the one it had from the user files, e.x: pic.jpg saves as 2613.jpg.

Im trying to do this to prevent that if there are 2 pics with same name the new one replace the old one, ive tried with javascript, php and yet i wouldnt be able to solve my problem, hope you guys may help me, by the way, im working using javascript, php, postgresql, jquery and ajax, if you need more details please let me know, and, once again, hope i can get some help from this community.

```
function guardar(){
if($('#titl').val() == '' || $('#categ').val() == '' || $('#cont').val()==''){
            alert("Todos los campos deben contener datos!");
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "noticias_php.php",
            data:{
                n : rand(),
                "accion" : "guardar",
                ID     : $('#id').val(),
                Titulo : $('#titl').val(),
                Categorias : $('#categ').val(),
                Contenido : $('#cont').val(),
                fecha: $('#fecha').val(),
                imagen: $('#img_id').val()

            },
            success: function(datos){
                var respuesta = explode("-*", datos);

                        if (respuesta[0] == "SI"){
                            aviso(respuesta[1]);
                            limpiar();
                        }else if (respuesta[0] == "NO"){
                            aviso(respuesta[1]);
                        }else{
                            aviso(datos);
                        }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question. It is very unreadable as a single sentence.

Comment: use sha(uniqid(microtime())) function in php to get random unique name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do here - I would recomend doing them at the server level using PHP.  The code you display seems to be client side JavaScript.

Typically you can generate a random number or datestamp (which may be more useful).  Then either replace or append this to the file name.  Depending  upon the usage of your site both these should suffice.

PHP random number generator - `rand(0000, 9999)`

PHP datestamp generator (Note if generating a date don't include : characters etc these will break some image urls) - `date("YmdHis")`

I often use some php like this to clean file names

```
$file_name = str_replace(" ", "_", rand(0000, 9999)."_".eregi_replace("[[:space:]]+", " ", strtolower($_FILES['image']['name'])));
```

This will not only make it unique by appending a 4 digit random number to the file name but will also stip all double spaces, make all lower case and also replace spaces with underscores.  It might not the be the cleanest but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use UUID (much the same as GUID). [Postgres UUID](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/uuid-ossp.html)

What version are you on? If on 9.1 try to just execute CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";

Are you on Windows or on some *niX box? See this link for some details on how to install depending on which you are on. [Install uuid-ossp module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163029/generate-uuid-in-windows-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to drive this based on the database - select max(id)+1 from ImageList. That way you guarantee uniqueness, instead of having a random value. You could also use a UUID, but they will be much longer filenames.

Comment: `select max(id)+1` will **not** guarantee uniqueness. A sequence is a **much** better alternative to this.

Answer (score 0):

`md5(microtime(true));` - this will be quite unique.

you can append `user_id` or `rand(0,1000)` to make it more unique.

alternative obviously is to use `tempnam` which would create unique temporary file in bash environment which you could reuse.